# tag-it :How to diss allow free text

Tags: tag-it

http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/

What should i do to avoid free text on tag-it?
I mean user should be able to tag only those strings suggested by auto compelte

```
$("#selector").tagit({
        // Options
        fieldName: "projects",
        autocomplete: {
            minLength: 2,
            source: function (request, response) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/xxx/xxxx',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        searchKey: request.term
                    },
                    success: function (data) {

                        response($.map(data, function (item) {

                            return { label: item.Name };
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        },

        showAutocompleteOnFocus: false,
        removeConfirmation: false,
        caseSensitive: false

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to somehow combine `autocomplete` with `beforeTagAdded` which discards tag from being added by returning false:

```
$("#selector").tagit({

    //...

    beforeTagAdded: function(event, ui) {
        return isSuggested(ui.tagLabel);
    }
});
```